# Pentaho 5.4.0 Community Edition Remote Execution

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-ctools

am using Pentaho community  edition 5.4.0 ,I explain My requirement  very Simply,

1) I have my jobs and transformation in my local windows machine and i like to execute those in my client machine ,So that i installed same Pentaho community version 5.4.0 on his machine. For Remote Execution i heard about Carte.bat service,I searched the installation procedure and configuration settings for remote execution,but i didn't get a clear idea about that,Please help me a clear step by step procedure for how to run remotely in my client machine .

2) Is there possible for Schedule those jobs and transformation in Pentaho Community edition 5..4.0 ? Is it possible please explain the same.

Thanks and Regards
Dhamodharan.

Comment: U can use any native scheduler. I use Jenkins to get remote access first of all and Jenkins as well has builtin scheduler. Even more, there is REST api to work with jobs, literally u can start job using http request.

Comment: @simar am new to jenkins i need to execute my .kjb job,before that i need to invoke .bash_profile for export some variables for running my job,could  you please help me in that ???

Comment: I think it is much better if u use carte. It looks like this is exactly what u need. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation

Comment: :-) ya thats good and your answer is suit for Remote Execution,But currently am looking for  Continues Integration (CI) in pentaho ETL ,in that am trying through Jenkins,So r u aware of Jenkins functionalities ,Could you please help me @simar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install jenkins
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins
At least read what variables are available in Jenkins. It is pretty handy to know them.

Download PDI KETTLE from http://pentaho.com unzip in any suitable directory. 
Configure executables and PDI variables as in here

[How to configure Database connection for production environment in Pentaho data integration Kettle transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349786/how-to-configure-database-connection-for-production-environment-in-pentaho-data/34350353#34350353)

Start jenkins and login into admin panel. Create an new job,
in paragraph **Build**  add **Execute shell** inside input text area add lines:

```
cd $WORKSPACE 
kitchen.sh -file=main.kjb
```

Done.

There are a lot of jenkins plugins.

You can add post-build actions:

- notice by email
- archive  publish result
- .... so on

Worth to use Jenkins if it is used for some other functionalities, means it is already exists in infrastructure, otherwise carte will be enought.

Variable configured in .bashrc and .bash_profile (User should be same as used for Jenkins)

```
#.bashrc
export KETTLE_HOME=/opt/R1/data-integration
export KETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=$KETTLE_HOME/simple-jndi
export PATH=$PATH:$KETTLE_HOME
```

To force evaluate .bashrc on ssh login add to .bash_profile

```
#.bash_profile
if [ -f .bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Then

```
source .bashrc
```

After restart Jenkins (not from admin panel)