# using variable names for a database connection in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am working on PDI kettle. Can we define a variable and use it in a database connection name. So that if in future if i need to change the connections in multiple transformations i would just change the variable value in kettle properties file?

Comment: You should try self before posting. It doesn't look like you have tried at all from this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349786/how-to-configure-database-connection-for-production-environment-in-pentaho-data/34350353#34350353

Answer (score 3):

Just use variables in the `Database Connection`.

For instance `${DB_HostName}`, and `${DB_Name}` etc.

Then just put it in your `kettle.properties:`

```
DB_HostName=localhost
```

You can see what fields that support variables by the `S` in the blue diamond.

[image: blue diamond s]